# How to emulate the kubectl apply edit-last-applied in Python K8S Client or Go client?

Tags: python, go, kubernetes, kubectl

We currently have deployments which mention the replica count in the yaml definition. We want to transition to using HPA for those deployments without any abrupt changes in the replica counts. We are running in to the problem mentioned in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25238.

Using the `kubectl apply edit-last-applied` command and removing the replica field works as expected. See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25238#issuecomment-406415297.

We want to run this in an automated manner and write code using the Python/Go K8S client, but the docs do not mention a way to emulate this. How can we run the equivalent of `kubectl apply edit-last-applied` using the client libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to use either an Unstructured or the new typed Apply builders. Or if you're using controller-runtime, you can use the older automatic patch diff tooling.

Long answer: ask me in Slack.